# UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync always returns failure

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using AspNet.Identity with a Winforms project.  I am finding the user successfully via the passed in username to UserManager.FindByNameAsync, but I cannot get my login to work with the passed in password.  I am able to log in just fine in my MVC app using the same database and same exact credentials.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<List<string>> VerifyUserNamePassword(string userName, string password)
    {
        var usermanager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new IdentityFrameworkDbContext()));

        var user = await usermanager.FindAsync(userName, password);

        //This is ALWAYS NULL!
        if (user != null) 
            label1.Text = "Success!";

        var u = await usermanager.FindByEmailAsync(userName);

        if (u != null)
        {
            //This works up to this point - check if password is correct

            var success = await usermanager.CheckPasswordAsync(u, password);

            //THIS IS ALWAYS FALSE!
            if (success)
                label1.Text = "YES THIS WORKED!";
        }            

        //This works, I get the Roles back and they are correct
        var users = await usermanager.GetRolesAsync(u.Id);

        return users.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The password hashing is dependent on these settings in the app.config or web.config.

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey decryption="" decryptionKey="" validation="" validationKey="" />
</system.web>
```

If they are not present the settings in the frameworks machine.config will be used. If you want multiple apps or deployments to use the same database then you must supply the same values across those deployments.

Seeing as you already have a running aps.net instance you should copy the values from the `web.config` to your windows form's `app.config` or from the machine.config on the web server.

Comment: I am lost here.  My other app that is using this database is a Asp.Net Core 2.0 app using MVC.  I don't have any of these values in the appsettings.json file, and when I look at the web.config that it creates when I publish it these values aren't in the web.config.

Comment: @user10529812 - You did not mention anything about asp.net core. I imagine the values are then retrieved from the machine.config but i could not say. You do need to make sure that all applications that share the same data source are using the same key values.