# CheckPasswordAsync always retruns false in .netcore

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity, claims-based-identity

below is the code to check password in login,

```
var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
var isCorrect = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Next user stored is implemented like below,

```
  public class UserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>, 
  IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser>,
    IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>
{...
 
  public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.Password.ToBase64());
    }

    public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByEmailAsync(string normalizedEmail, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = 
     adapter.GetUserbyEmail(normalizedEmail);
        return Task.FromResult(user);
    }

 ....
 ..}
```

Not understanding why CheckPasswordAsync returns always false. Is there a way to override it?

Comment: Can it be the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149535/usermanager-checkpasswordasync-always-returns-failure ?

Comment: Why are you converting the stored password hash to base64? Are you sure it isn't already in base64 format?

Comment: Your question is missing method where you create user, we can only guess what are you doing wrong without it.

Comment: yes my password which is stored in db is not in base64 string format.

Comment: updated method where we create user

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: I am not using that method any more. Manually doing comparsion.